# Adding cocoapods to a iOS workspace created with cordova 6.5

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cocoapods

I am using Apache Cordova 6.5, adding iOS platform and trying to use cocoapods inside the workspace created by the cordova iOS project.

When I run the command

> pod install

The Xcode project won't compile and I get the following errors

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

Here are the steps I have done to get this issue:

- Create a new Cordova 6.5 project

> cordova create app1

- Go to the project folder and add iOS platform

> cd app1/
>
> cordova platform add ios

- Go to the iOS project folder and run pods

> cd platforms/ios
>
> pod init
>
> pod install

I tried with both basic podfile and a one where I added my workspace name

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
workspace 'HelloCordova'
xcodeproj 'HelloCordova.xcodeproj'

target 'HelloCordova' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for HelloCordova

end
```

Any idea on how to fix that?

PS: I am using cordova 6.5.0, cordova-ios 4.3.1, Xcode 8.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue was solved by modifying ***build-debug.xcconfig*** and ***build-release.xcconfig*** files and replacing

```
#include "../pods-release.xcconfig"
```

with a path like

```
#include "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-HelloCordova/Pods-HelloCordova.release.xcconfig
```

And after that do again

```
pod install
```

Comment: you saved my day. Tried hundred of suggestions none worked for me. You gave a rite shot, thank you.